# Reading STEP properties with pythonocc

Tags: c++, python, geometry, cad, opencascade

I'm struggling to read presentation layer assignments out of an AP214 STEP CAD file with pythonocc. The file will read in, but I only get 1 shape and I'm not sure how to access any other attributes of the OCC.TopoDS.TopoDS_Shape object. I tried to go through the c++ from OCE but unfortunately my c++ is rusty and I failed to find anything helpful

I have lines at the end of the file like the following that assign the properties I'd like to use:

```
#27092=PRESENTATION_LAYER_ASSIGNMENT('PROPERTY001','PROPERTY001|ANSA_Thick=1.',(#587));
#27093=PRESENTATION_LAYER_ASSIGNMENT('PROPERTY002','PROPERTY002|ANSA_Thick=1.',(#24235));
```

Where PROPERTY001 and PROPERTY002 are the names of the properties I need to keep.

Ultimately what I'm looking to do is read in a STEP file, apply a mesh to the surface, and output an STL file while maintaining the property definitions such that the output STL file has multiple solids that correspond to each presentation_layer_assignment property from the input STEP file.

I'm using pythonocc-0.6a and OCEv11

Does anyone have any experience with this or suggestions? Thanks